# IF/Else statement giving me wrong number

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I'm trying to set the variable "productid" to a product number in the URL and set it to another variable "product**ID**". The if statement works. The else statement, which is my fallback product number in case there is no product number in the url, gives me this: tp://localhost:63342/IntegralWebsite/index.php.

Here's my code:

```js
function prod() {
    let productid;
      if (url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("ID=") + 3).split("#")[0]) {
          productid = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("ID=") + 3).split("#")[0]; //Get product ID from url
          alert(productid);
          // localStorage.setItem('productid', productid);
      } else {
        productid = 167160840221;
          // localStorage.setItem('productid', productid);
          alert(productid);
      }
    return productid;
  }

  let productID = prod();
  alert(productID);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No that is the `if` part giving you that. There is no `ID=` in your URL, so the substring is happening at index -1+3=2, i.e. removing the first 2 characters

Comment: WOAH! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing a lot of things in a line and that can be a problem.

```
url.lastIndexOf("ID=")
```

I url has not "ID=" returns -1, then -1+3 = 2 and so the substring is cutting the first two chars "ht".

Code corrected (and a bit optimized):

```
//var url = "http://sadfsdf?ID=324123413#sdfasdf"; //IDURL
var url = "http://sadfsdf"; //NOIDURL

function prod() {
  let productid = 167160840221,
    index = url.lastIndexOf("ID=");
  if (index >= 0) {
    let urlProductId = url.substring(index + 3).split("#")[0];
    if (urlProductId) {
      productid = urlProductId;
    }
  }
  return productid;
}

let productID = prod();
alert(productID);
```

Answer (score 0):

It never makes it into the else statement. When lastIndexOf does not match it returns -1 which you then add a 3 to. That is used to substring, so chips off a couple of chars from the non matching url.